# Ionic cordova-plugin-camera crash the application after take picture

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-camera, ionic4, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic application that uses cordova-plugin-camera: 4.1.0 version, In a Redmi with Android version 9 and MIUI version 11.0.3, it doesn't work. I can open the camera and click the picture but after that app crashes and restart this app.
Please suggest a better solution to solve it.

Comment: can you share code ?

Comment: upgrade to latest version i.e: `5.0.1` - also update your device to latest android version.

Comment: Hi, @NajamUsSaqib Thanks for your reply. I updated both version Cordova camera plugin and android but still coming up the same issue.

Comment: is it only Redmi issue? have you checked it with other brands??

Comment: Hi, @NajamUsSaqib my app is working fine in other phones and in this Redmi phone my app was also working fine for the last 3 months but last few days after capturing the image, it is crashing up.

Comment: have you tried the solution posted in Plugin's github's repo?

Answer (score 1):

**On Android 11 Ionic4 Camera leads to crash/ restart the application.**

My solution which worked for me after is that to *allowEdit:false*
Here is my complete config code

```
  options: CameraOptions = {
   quality: 30,
   correctOrientation: true,
   allowEdit: false,
   targetWidth: 400,
   targetHeight: 600,
   destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
   encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
   mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE

}
galleryOptions: CameraOptions = {
 quality: 30,
 correctOrientation: true,
 allowEdit: false,
 targetWidth: 400,
 targetHeight: 600,
 sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
 destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
 encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
 mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}
```

Comment: Hi.. may i know which version of the plugin are you using.

Comment: "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.33.0", "cordova-plugin-camera": "^5.0.2" . After few more research, I came to know that the Android 11 update is not perfectly suitable for all device (So I choose better to off allow edit). which is creating an issue with app.  And the same app is working fine on another Android 11 device.

Comment: correct.. after two days struggle i too found that.. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

cordova 7 not supporting new android sdk,
you should use cordova 10 or like me drop the cordova plugin and make use of capacitor camera instead:

[capacitor camera doc](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera)

Answer (score 0):

call this.backgroundMode.enable() just before this.camera.getPicture method
and disable it before resolving.

Make sure to add BackgroundMode in Providers array and import it in your component.
Follow

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode