# Ionic3 with Cordova application crash randomly in some android 11

Tags: android, cordova, camera, ionic3

Mobile application of Ionic 3 with Cordova have crash/restart in some android 11 devices whenever we will open camera.

Comment: Did you find any solution for it? If yes, please post.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova 7 issue to support android sdk 30

look at this answer:

[cordoca camera crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73225835/4751073)